# Convert select query results into Json

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to execute a select query on a table and I need this result in a **JSON** format or in an **excel sheet**. I want to do this using query only and I'm using **SQL Server 2014**.

Here is the table schema

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
(

   Id int primary key identity(1,1),
   Name nvarchar(200),
   About nvarchar(2000),
   Age int,
   AddressId int
 )
```

I need to get values from Id, Name, About and Age into a JSON List

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`JSON AUTO` would make quick work of this in but JSON support is available only in SQL Server 2016 and later, including Azure SQL Database. For a T-SQL solution in SQL 2014 and earlier, you'll need to build the JSON string yourself.

Below is an example that uses a `FOR XML` subquery to concatenate the result into JSON format and adds the outermost `[` and `]` for the array. Note that this does not handle characters that must be escaped in JSON (`\` and `"`) so you'll need to use `REPLACE` to escape those if contained in your data.

```
SELECT '[' + STUFF((
    SELECT
          ',{'
        + '"Id":'+CAST(Id AS varchar(10)) + ','
        + COALESCE('"Name":"' + Name + '",','')
        + COALESCE('"About":"' + About + '",','')
        + COALESCE('"Age":'+CAST(Age AS varchar(10)) + ',','')
        + COALESCE('"AddressId":'+CAST(AddressId AS varchar(10)), '')
        + '}'
    FROM TestTable
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(MAX)'),1,1,'')
    + ']';
```

Comment: It works correctly if all the columns have value, All the field except Id are nullable here. If a row contains any null column then this query will ignore that row.

Comment: @Sajithv, I added `COALESCE` to handle NULL values.

Answer (score 10):

For SQL server 2017

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
  ID int PRIMARY KEY,
  Name varchar(50),
  teamName varchar(255),
  Create_Date DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (1,NULL,'TEST1','2017-01-02');
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (2,NULL,'TEST2',NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (3,'KK','TEST3','2017-01-02');
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (4,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

Try below way  here i provide an example

```
SELECT 
       ID,  
       Name,  
       teamName,  
       Create_Date 
   FROM mytable 
   FOR JSON AUTO
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/81350/1

```
JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B
[{"ID":1,"teamName":"TEST1","Create_Date":"2017-01-02T00:00:00"},{"ID":2,"teamName":"TEST2"},{"ID":3,"Name":"KK","teamName":"TEST3","Create_Date":"2017-01-02T00:00:00"},{"ID":4}]
```

For below vesion of sql 2017 server:

1st create a scaler function

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-JSON] (@IncludeHead int,@ToLowerCase int,@XML xml)
Returns varchar(max)
AS
Begin
    Declare @Head varchar(max) = '',@JSON varchar(max) = ''
    ; with cteEAV as (Select RowNr=Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL))
                            ,Entity    = xRow.value('@*[1]','varchar(100)')
                            ,Attribute = xAtt.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                            ,Value     = xAtt.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                       From  @XML.nodes('/row') As R(xRow) 
                       Cross Apply R.xRow.nodes('./@*') As A(xAtt) )
          ,cteSum as (Select Records=count(Distinct Entity)
                            ,Head = IIF(@IncludeHead=0,IIF(count(Distinct Entity)<=1,'[getResults]','[[getResults]]'),Concat('{"status":{"successful":"true","timestamp":"',Format(GetUTCDate(),'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss '),'GMT','","rows":"',count(Distinct Entity),'"},"results":[[getResults]]}') ) 
                       From  cteEAV)
          ,cteBld as (Select *
                            ,NewRow=IIF(Lag(Entity,1)  over (Partition By Entity Order By (Select NULL))=Entity,'',',{')
                            ,EndRow=IIF(Lead(Entity,1) over (Partition By Entity Order By (Select NULL))=Entity,',','}')
                            ,JSON=Concat('"',IIF(@ToLowerCase=1,Lower(Attribute),Attribute),'":','"',Value,'"') 
                       From  cteEAV )
    Select @JSON = @JSON+NewRow+JSON+EndRow,@Head = Head From cteBld, cteSum
    Return Replace(@Head,'[getResults]',Stuff(@JSON,1,1,''))
End
-- Parameter 1: @IncludeHead 1/0
-- Parameter 2: @ToLowerCase 1/0 (converts field name to lowercase
-- Parameter 3: (Select * From ... for XML RAW)
```

Then use this function json conversion below query is an example

```
Declare @Table table (ID int,Active bit,First_Name varchar(50),Last_Name varchar(50),EMail varchar(50))
Insert into @Table values
(1,1,'John','Smith','john.smith@email.com'),
(2,0,'Jane','Doe'  ,'jane.doe@email.com')

Select A.ID
      ,A.Last_Name
      ,A.First_Name
      ,B.JSON
From  @Table A 
Cross Apply (Select JSON=[dbo].[udf-Str-JSON](0,1,(Select A.* For XML Raw)) ) B
```

Comment: This will work for SQL server 2017 version. I am using SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 6):

> From SQL-Server 2016+, you can use `JSON AUTO` to return `Json`:

`Select * 
   From Customers
 FOR JSON AUTO;`

If you expect to return just a single row, then you can add `Without_Array_Wrapper` after `FOR JSON AUTO` with a comma after the `AUTO` keyword, and you will get an `object` instead of an `array`:

`Select * 
   From Customers 
 FOR JSON AUTO, Without_Array_Wrapper;`

*Note: If you add the `Without_Array_Wrapper` and return multiple rows, you will get a newly populated `object type` but won't get any error - which requires carefulness as you won't know if anything is wrong and might hit you later when exercising the data.*

Answer (score 4):

```
From SQL-Server 2016+, you can use JSON AUTO to return Json:
```

I know two way to return query in JSON format.
If your query is from one table or only return a single table (as usual) you can use JSON PATH or JSON AUTO

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
(

   Id int primary key identity(1,1),
   Name nvarchar(200),
   About nvarchar(2000),
   Age int,
   AddressId int
 )

INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable(Name,About,Age,AddressId)      
 VALUES (N'John' , NULL ,21, 16),(N'Mehdi' , 'Developer' ,32, 15)
```

query is

```
select * from [TestTable] for JSON PATH
```

output :

```
[{
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Mehdi",
        "About": "Developer",
        "Age": 32,
        "AddressId": 15
    }, {
        "Id": 3,
        "Name": "John",
        "Age": 21,
        "AddressId": 16
    }
]
```

Notice that NULL values do not show on result. For showing the null values, [INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES] must be added at the end of the query.

```
SELECT * FROM [TestTable] WHERE id=2 FOR JSON PATH , INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
```

output:

```
[{
        "Id": 3,
        "Name": "John",
        "About": null,
        "Age": 21,
        "AddressId": 16
    }
]
```

For the query that only return an object, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER must be added at the end of query the brackets are remove from the result.

```
SELECT * FROM [TestTable] WHERE id=2 FOR JSON PATH , INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES , WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

output :
{
"Id": 3,
"Name": "John",
"About": null,
"Age": 21,
"AddressId": 16
}
For adding sub query for example the user's contracts or user's family names.

there two way :
1-

```
SELECT
  * , 
ContractList = (SELECT* FROM contract where UserId = 2 FOR JSON PATH)
FROM TestTable  FOR JSON PATH
```

2-

```
SELECT
  * , 
(JSON_QUERY((SELECT* FROM contract WHERE UserId = 2 FOR JSON PATH))) AS ContractList
FROM TestTable  FOR JSON PATH
```

output:

```
 [{
            "Id": 3,
            "Name": "John",
            "About": null,
            "Age": 21,
            "AddressId": 16 , 
            "ContractList" : [{...}, {...}]
        }
 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so much, your answer came to my rescue after a week-long search.

Had to make a few changes to suit my scenario and add quotes around the code

```
SELECT '[' + STUFF((
    SELECT
          ',['
        + '"'+ CAST(s.Code AS varchar(10)) + '"' + ','
        + COALESCE(''+CAST(COUNT(s.ControlNumber) AS varchar(10)), '')
        + ']'
    FROM school s
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Class] cc ON cc.SchoolID = s.SchoolID 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Subject] s ON s.subjectID = cc.subjectID 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].Marks ms ON s.MarkID = c.CaseStatusID 
    WHERE ms.Created BETWEEN '2021-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-04-07 23:59:59' 
    AND s.subjectID IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) 
    Group By s.Code
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(MAX)'),1,1,'')
    + ']';
```

Output

```
[["za-ec",14],["za-fs",5],["za-gt",3],["za-mp",14],["za-nc",2],["za-nl",8],["za-np",5],["za-nw",6],["za-wc",15]]
```