# How to select multiple key-value pairs into a single column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, key-value

I have a database with a table for products and a table for key-value pairs to associate random data to each product.

- Products table:  productId(pk), name
- ProductDetails table:  productId(fk), name, value

I'd like to run a query something like this:

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  (???) as details 
from Products p 
JOIN ProductDetails pd on pd.productId = p.productId
WHERE (??? there exists a value with pd.key = 'foo' and pd.value like '%bar%` ???)
```

I'd like to get back data that looks like this:

```
productID   name        details
----------- ----------- -----------------------------------------------------------
22          flizbot     {"sponsor": "fred", "foo", "casbar", "planet": "venus"}
354         munchbat    {"foo": "barrel", "power": "over9000"}
...
```

How exactly would I write a query like that?

Comment: While asking a question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT, T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert select query results into Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51798221/convert-select-query-results-into-json)

Comment: @devlincarnate Not relevant because the JSON keys need to be dynamic, and SQL cannot do that

Comment: @Charlieface : I'm curious how you know the json keys need to be dynamic based on what the OP has posted.

Comment: @devlincarnate `{"foo": "barrel"` and `pd.key = 'foo' and pd.value like '%bar%`` seems quite clear to me that key `foo` is dynamic because it comes from the `key` column

Comment: @Charlieface - that's right - I thought that pd.key = 'foo' would make it clear that only at runtime would I know the name of the key for the query and that some records might not have the key.     This is similar to how a document database in the cloud is flexible about what keys are present on each document record.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two separate questions here

1. **How to filter based on values in a group**

   That is simply answered with a `HAVING` clause and a conditional `COUNT`
   `HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN pd.[key] = 'foo' AND pd.[value] LIKE '%bar%' THEN 1 END) > 0;`
2. **How to get dynamic JSON key-value pairs from column values**

   This is more complex.

   Since `FOR JSON` requires key names as columns, you cannot use it without dynamic SQL.

```sql
DECLARE @cols = (
    SELECT
)

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
SELECT 
    p.id,
    p.name, 
    pd.details 
FROM Products p
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT details = (SELECT
' +
(
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(
        QUOTENAME([key]) + N' = MIN(CASE WHEN [key] = ' + QUOTENAME([value], '''') + N' THEN [value] END)'
      AS nvarchar(max)), N',
'   )
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT [key]
        FROM ProductDetails
    ) pd
)
+ N'
    FROM ProductDetails pd
    WHERE pd.productId = p.productId
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN pd.[key] = ''foo'' AND pd.[value] LIKE ''%bar%'' THEN 1 END) > 0
    FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)
) pd;
';

PRINT @sql;  -- for testing

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

An alternative is to build up the JSON manually using `STRING_AGG` and `STRING_ESCAPE`. **I would strongly favour this solution as being the easier to write and maintain.**

```sql
SELECT 
    p.id,
    p.name, 
    N'{' +
     STRING_AGG(
        N'"' + STRING_ESCAPE(pd.[key], 'json')
        + N'":"' + STRING_ESCAPE(pd.[value], 'json') + N'"'
      , N','
     ) + N'}'
    AS details 
FROM Products p 
JOIN ProductDetails pd on pd.productId = p.productId
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN pd.[key] = 'foo' AND pd.[value] LIKE '%bar%' THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!